# Simple multi-client voice chat python, when more then two client connected sound distorted

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, voice

As mentioned in the title, my program cannot handle more then 2 clients.
The sound gets distorted and choppy, and i cant figure out how to fix it.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem?
Thanks!

This is my server:

```
import socket
import select


class ChatServer:
    def __init__(self):

        self.CONNECTION_LIST = []
        self.chat_server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.chat_server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 50000))
        self.chat_server_socket.listen(5)

        self.CONNECTION_LIST.append(self.chat_server_socket)

        print "Server Started!"

    def broadcast(self, sock, data):
        for current_socket in self.CONNECTION_LIST:
            if current_socket != self.chat_server_socket and current_socket != sock:
                try:
                    current_socket.send(data)
                except:
                    pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(self.CONNECTION_LIST, [], [])

            for current_socket in rlist:
                if current_socket is self.chat_server_socket:
                    (new_socket, address) = self.chat_server_socket.accept()
                    self.CONNECTION_LIST.append(new_socket)
                    print "%s connected to the server" % str(address)
                else:
                    try:
                        data = current_socket.recv(1024)
                        self.broadcast(current_socket, data)
                    except socket.error:
                        print "%s left the server" % str(address)
                        current_socket.close()
                        self.CONNECTION_LIST.remove(current_socket)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatServer().run()
```

This is my client:

```
import socket
import pyaudio
import wave
import thread

# record
CHUNK = 1024 # 512
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 20000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 50000))

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

receive_stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
send_stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("Voice chat running")

def receive_data():
    while True:
        try:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            receive_stream.write(data)
        except:
            pass


def send_data():
    while True:
        try:
            data = send_stream.read(CHUNK)
            s.sendall(data)
        except:
            pass

thread.start_new_thread(receive_data, ())
thread.start_new_thread(send_data, ())

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: increase `CHUNK` maybe?? how can we figure out your problem?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This is excatly why I poseted my entire code.. and I already tried to icrease CHUNK, its not the problem.

Comment: Please try to reduce the code to a [mcve] so people can reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: It looks like you are using blocking sockets?  If so, consider what happens whenever any client fails to send a packet exactly on time -- the server will be blocked inside the recv() call until the packet arrives; and while it's inside the recv() call, it can't receive audio from any other client.  I suggest setting your sockets to non-blocking mode in the server, so that one slow client doesn't cause audio underruns on all other clients.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I just tried and it didn't work :( I can't figure out how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried spawning multiple threads for when new users connect? And then having some control structure like a semaphore control their actions between the 2?

It seems like your program is receiving 2 audio streams, and trying to process + display them in the same program. This could easily cause overlap and ambiguity, as you don't know how these packets are being processed (TDM? FDM?).

If you had multiple threads, you could just request access to the semaphore before you process something so you know exactly what order things are being handled in. No need to predict how the audio data is being processed.